# I want to check no of clicks of post in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to check no of click in my post (wordpress). How i can do using plugin and some query . I install the plugin (Post view Counter) but this plugin doesn't show previous no of clicks.

Comment: You will not get any answer like this ! Share the code that you've tried, the plugins that you've used and the problems that you are facing..

Comment: _“but this plugin doesn't show previous no of clicks”_ - probably because they weren’t recorded anywhere to begin with …

Comment: @misorude then how i know no of clicks.

Comment: Well if no one counted them so far - then you simply don’t … (You could perhaps fall back on log file analysis to get some numbers for the time before you implemented or configured something that explicitly counts them.)

Comment: How can it show previous number of clicks if there was nothing recording the clicks to begin with. What you are asking is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in plain Javascript

```js
var cnt=0;

function showCount()
{
 cnt=parseInt(cnt)+parseInt(1);
 var divData=document.getElementById("cnt");
 divData.innerHTML="Click counts ("+cnt +")";

}
```

```html
<input type="button" id="btnClick" value="Button" onclick="showCount();"/>
<div id="cnt"></div>
```

Comment: @ Aravind brother i want to know wordpress post clicks

Comment: @SonuKumarPandit Sorry.. I don't have much idea about Wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

Use Google Analytics plugins.
Someone like Analytify. https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-analytify